# Unexpected request size for Asp.WebForms application after update of components

Tags: asp.net, http

I've got the following problem:

We've updated our components. Before the update a page request size was 22kb in size (140k characters, including whitespace). After the update the request size is 180~kb (180k characters, including whitespace).

I would have assumed there's a direct relation of request answer length and the characters sent so i can't quite explain how a 30%~ increase in characters results in 9 times the request content sent.

Does this ring a bell to anyone? I can't quite see where the difference is comming from.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this was, that the old version has gzip compression enabled while the new one does not, despite the configuration beeing set to have it enabled. so it's just a matter of research as to why it is not returning gzip encoded content now.